# Error When Named LOV assigned to column in interactive report

Tags: oracle-apex

When in a Interactive Report managed by rowid, and named LOV is assigned to a  column  I am facing following error:

ORA-20001: get_dbms_sql_cursor error ORA-01445: cannot select ROWID from, or  sample, a join view without a key-preserved table

If it is managed by Primary Key ,issue gets resolved.Can anybody suggest  a reason for this error.

Comment: what version of apex, 4.2? And you mean you set the column type to "based on list of values"?

Comment: Yes version 4.2 And column type : Display as Text (based on LOV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From oracle's [forum](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2434226)

You need to set an alias to the rowid column in your query

like:
    select rowid as column_rowid from emp;